# upserting values in salesforce usin mule4

Tags: salesforce, dataweave, upsert, mule4

Am trying to upsert some values in salesforce object using mule4 transform my input is below

Transform shape:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
[{
Name: vars.det,
Request_Body__c: vars.Req

}]
```

The input payload am upserting is

input:

```
[{Name= MuleSoft--Salesforce, Request_Body__c= {
data = {
        schema = PZAhU2AlqQtEHKOut4Rctg,
        payload = {
        Job_Prev_Name__c =Mule UWW, LastModifiedDate= 2020 - 09 - 15,
        ChangeEventHeader = {
        commitNumber = 1072316585812,
        commitUser = 0057000001 cAAA,
        sequenceNumber = 1,
        entityName = ATI__c,
        changeType = UPDATE,
        changedFields = 
        }, Job_Name__c = Mule UWX, Name = CMule UWX}, event= {
        replayId = 0311
        }
        },
        channel = /data/ATI_Job__ChangeEvent
        }
}]
```

While upserting am getting error like invalid input

How can i modify the "Request_Body__c" filed inorder to upsert in salesforce?

Comment: If you want to upsert the `payload` why do you use `vars.Req`?

Comment: am upsertiing mutliple fileds at same time, one of the field is Request_Body__c.
So am storing the payload in variable vars.Req and calling it in field Request_Body__c

Comment: You need to specify which object needs to be upserted. You can't update the CDC(change data capture events) which is specified in `/data/ATI_Job_ChangeEvent`